# How to use isActive with a lookup field value

Tags: user

I want to see if a user who is named in a field has an active account by using isActive.

I can use this successfully :

```
a.Owner.isActive
```

but I want to try and use that with a field value of a custom field (lookup to User) such as this :

```
a.Field_Manager__c.isActive
```

but I'm unable to do that because of an error : 'Invalid foreign key relationship'

I thought maybe I could do it this way :

```
a.Field_Manager__c.Username.isActive
```

but that doesn't work right either

Does anybody know how I can accomplish this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the relationship name wrong; custom relationships are `__r`, not `__c`.

So:

```
a.Field_Manager__c.Username.isActive
```

Should be:

```
a.Field_Manager__r.Username.isActive
```

When in doubt, you can check in your Enterprise WSDL for relationship names.

**Update**

After re-reading the question and comment below, it is unclear what `Username` is and what `Field_Manager__c` is a lookup to; if `Field_Manager__c` is a lookup(User) then the query will probably be:

```
a.Field_Man__r.isActive
```

Comment: oh, it didn't even occur to me to do that. I was intentionally referring to the field, not the relationship Thanks Mike ! However, here's something weird : The relationship name for that field is different (Field_Man__r) and if I use Field_Man__r I am still getting that same error. However, if I change it to Field_Manager__r I do not get the error. How is that ? Shouldn't I be using the proper name of the relationship, not just the field name with __r after it ?

Comment: Can you expand on the relationships/objects involved? Is Field_Manager__c a lookup to User or a different object?

Comment: Yes, Field_Manager__c is a lookup to User.

Comment: I have updated my answer. In addition, when building new queries, I find https://workbench.developerforce.com extremely useful.

Comment: It's in a custom object. I don't think that matters, but I just wanted to mention it. And the Child Relationship name associated with it is : Field_Man__r. But I keep getting errors when trying to use Field_Man__r.isActive ; but not when I try Field_Manager__r.isActive. (which is the name of the field, not the child relationship name)

Comment: Without knowing the schema, it's going to be hard. Can you try workbench (see link above) to generate the SOQL?

Comment: Mike, thank you very much for the reference to Workbench. I've never heard of that before. I included the portion of my code which is using this in my original post. I don't know if that would shed any light on this or not. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Mike - just fyi : the Field_Manager__r reference is returning results in Workbench. Field_Man__r (the proper relationship name) doesn't work. Very weird. Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: Field_Man__r is the Child Relationship from the User object. So you can get a list of object records from User.Field_Man__r. Field_Manager__r is the object relationship from the Account. so Account.Field_Manager__r refers to the specific User that's populated into that field.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
a.Field_Manager__r.isActive
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sf_Ninja. I responded to Mike above. You both gave the same solution, but I still had a question for it all.

Comment: no worries, glad to help